# I Do Have a Huge database data around 65K , Without Timeout Error How do I get that to the view? someone suggest chunk or laravel queue

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, laravel

I Have huge database and I have to compare same data with which I have stored in local storage as xml and i have to get it to the view something like below,
But belowfunction i get all data but can't view data because of loading time and can't laravel view render that much data at a time? Please help.

```
 $files = File::allFiles(storage_path('xml'));

 foreach($files as $filename1) {

     $xml_file = file_get_contents($filename1, FILE_TEXT);      
     $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_file, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA); 

     $json = json_encode($xml);
     $data[] = json_decode($json,TRUE);
 }
 //dd($data);
     foreach($data as $val){   
         //dd($val);
         foreach($val as $dan){
          //dd($da);
             foreach($dan as $da){
                 //dd($da);
                 $no[] = $da['JS_UniqueConsignRef'];                   
                 foreach($da['Order_Details'] as $n){

                 }                        
             }  
         }                
     }  

   $shipment = Shipment::whereIn('JS_UniqueConsignRef',$no)->get()->chunk(1000);

     foreach($shipment as $ship){}
     //dd($ship);

 return view('sitemap',compact('files','ship','shipment'));
}
```

Comment: In what sense is 65k 'huge'?

Comment: Those 4 nested for each cause the timeout. Could you restrict that at least to 2.

Comment: You should fetch those data asynchronously with pagination.

Comment: You may want to use Queues if you have timeout issues: process in the background and then use events to display it back to the user

Comment: @ChristopheHubert Can you please explain that in details , i am looking similar solution for that?

Comment: @strawberry - maybe he means 65k records? Not huge for a database, but big enough to start choking some text editors and spreadsheet software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Queues to avoid this timeout issue - I highly advise you to look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues) for that.

One of the ways to implement is the following:

```
$xml_file = file_get_contents($filename1, FILE_TEXT);      

dispatch(function () use ($xml_file) {
    // Your logic here
});
```

If you need to pass back the information to the user, then you can use [Job Events](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#job-events) and a logic on your own to display it.